# Stemming texts separates words into letters

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, stemming, lemmatization

I am trying to process my text using tokenization, stemming, normalization and stop-word/punctuation removal, etc.
When I use **snowball stemming technique**, my text gets separated into letters with commas in between.

```
def processed_tweets(text):

  punctuate_text= str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation+string.digits)
  text = text.translate(punctuate_text)

  tokens = word_tokenize(text)

  stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
  filtered_words = [w for w in tokens if not w in stop_words]

  #applying stemming 
  snow_stemmer = SnowballStemmer(language='english')
  text = [snow_stemmer.stem(word) for word in text]

  return text


tweet_df['processed_tweets'] = tweet_df['Tweet Body'].apply(processed_tweets)
tweet_df.head()
```

This is the output I am getting:

[image: Output]

Following is the output for `print(tokens)`

[image]

This is not the case when using lemmatization though. Is there an issue on how I am writing my code or the technique I am using (stemming vs lemmatization)?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `for word in text.split(' ')`? Python assumes you want to iterate over the characters of a string.

Comment: can you show the output of `print(tokens)`?

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal `word_tokenize(text)` should do the equivalent of `text.split(' ')`

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat I have edited the question to include the output of ```print(tokens)``` . Is ```text.split(' ')``` even necessary if tokenize is present then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much a very small misunderstanding on the use of tokenize on my part. Editing how I apply stemming to tokenized words instead of the 'text' string works:

```
text = [snow_stemmer.stem(word) for word in filtered_words]
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, im not really into that type of processing text, and i dont really know exactly what are you looking for...
But something that i understood, is that you are remooving all the punctuation and digits with the module "maketrans" (i would have used other methods but it does the job plus it is fast).

But i do not get why you **tokenize**, when you literally just removed all the punctuation and numbers... Literally **tokenize** is the best way to split a text and **get** all the punctuation, numbers, symbols... That you literally just removed.
Maybe try to replace:

> tokens = word_tokenize(text)

with:

```py
list_words = text.split()
```

The function split cuts by the space and removes it, and appends all the text to a list.

Comment: AFAIK `maketrans` + `word_tokenize` is a pretty standard preprocessing step in NLP

Comment: @Azogue99 Removing punctuation, tokenising and basic noise cleaning are all parts of text processing techniques. Pretty much wherever I checked includes the above steps.